Debug Console throwing errors
How do I get rid of this error that the debug console throws all the time when StreamBuilding from Firestore?
Null check operator used on a null value

In the debug console, I always get this error even when I add ! or ? to final numbPaidPass = snaped.data!.docs.length;.
Code example
StreamBuilder(
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(widget.adsCollection)
          .doc(appData.rideId)
          .collection(widget.requestCollection)
          .where("PassUID", isNotEqualTo: uid)
          .where("AdStatus", whereIn: ["Approved", "Started", 
           "Completed"])
          .where("Pay", isEqualTo: "Paid")
          .snapshots(),
builder: (context, snaped){
final numbPaidPass = snaped.data!.docs.length;
}
);

